# Migrate single VM to azure

Tags: azure, server, migration, virtual-machine

We are trying to migrate a VM in a private cloud to azure. This VM has multiple web applications and databases. We don't have access to the virtualization, just access to this single VM.

Can anyone suggest how we can do the migration to azure with just having access to the VM itself?

Regards
Anup

Answer (score 0):

- *As far as I know and as per the document, we can't migrate Single VM without having access to Virtualization.*
- *Because while processing Migration you need to generate Project Key where you need to have access Virtualization.*
  [image]
- *You can go through the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-discover-vmware) for further details.*